# Vuetify v-select not showing data on firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuetify.js

I deployed my vue.js app to firebase hosting

on my local install it works flawless, however on the firebase deploy it only shows the standard value and nothing else. You can not even switch the selected value by using the arrow keys or w/e

```
      <v-select
        :searchable="false"
        v-model="selectedLanguage"
        :options="languages"
        @input="onLanguageChange()">
      </v-select>
```

v-select is also added as dependencie

```
 "vue-select": "^2.5.1",
```

I built the project with yarn build --modern

Comment: How about you try to reproduce your issue in a fiddle or a codepen, or provide a way to reproduce it? Then we can get a look at it and help you further...

Comment: You need to share much more of your code and not only the `v-select`. How are the different objects (e.g. `languages`) set/calculated?